# Need of Controllers in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

What is controllers in frameworks ? 
Please answer not as developer point of view but logical point of view.
why we need it ?
what is main core purpose of controllers ?

Comment: They are a lot of available resources in books and online about the MVC concept. What exactly would you like to be clarified? Also, I'm not clear what you mean by logical point of view...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about MVC theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are used to split application logic from presentation or storage logic.

The Models store data and their associated manipulation methods. 
Views are designed to hold only data relevant to presenting the data.

This leaves a gap of how to link data to the correct view and also how to control actions on the data. It is for this purpose that the controller was added. The controller quite aptly controls how data is manipulated and presented.

As such the controller serves the purpose of acting as a bridge between the users request and the system the user is interacting with. For instance if the user is manipulating forms to change the stored data then the controller takes responsibility for checking the data submitted by the user before manipulating the stored data.

In a broader sense of the word the controller is there for a separation of concerns.
The models need only be concerned on how to store and manipulate the data. They don't have to worry on how the user interacts or how it is presented to the user.
The views likewise only deal with presentation they don't concern themselves at all with what the user submitted to the system or how the data came to be. The view is only there to present the delivered data.
The controller glues these two together. A result of this is that each section can be developed/updated/replaced without breaking the entire system.

For more information ask a more specific question or read one of the many books on the topic of MVC.